# Como armazenar retorno AJAX para utilizar como parâmetro de outra função

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

Função principal, que terá como retorno o valor `chave = data.chave`:

```
var chave = '';

$scope.submitForm = function() {
        $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'validar.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          data : dados,
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
         })
         .success(function(data) {
            if (data.errors) {
              $scope.erro = data.errors.errovalidar;
            } else {
              chave = data.chave;
              $('#imprimir-danfe').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
          })
    };
```

Função secundária, que deverá receber como parâmetro o valor retornado da função principal (`chave`):

```
var imprimir_d = document.getElementById('imprimir');
    imprimir_d.addEventListener('click', function() {
        $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'imprimir.php',
          data : chave,
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
         })
    });
```

Contudo, da forma que está, quando faço `console.debug(chave)`, dentro da função secundária e retornado "`undefined`"

Comment: Seu código deveria funcionar. Pois tem uma variável global que captura o valor. O submit ocorre antes de pressionar o botão com id "imprimir"?

Comment: No primeiro script você não definiu a variável chave como global. Tire o var e deixe somente: chave = '';. Agora vai dar certo.

Comment: O submit ocorre antes de pressionar o botão com o id "imprimir". @mauhumor

Comment: O problema ainda persiste. @WillianCoqueiro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após `$('#imprimir-danfe').removeAttr('disabled');`....
coloca: `$('#imprimir-danfe').attr('meu_valor', chave );`

E em depois é só pegar o valor da chave:

```
var imprimir_d = document.getElementById('imprimir');
    imprimir_d.addEventListener('click', function() {
        minha_chave = $('#imprimir-danfe').attr('meu_valor');
        $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'imprimir.php',
          data : minha_chave,
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
         })
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar o `$scope.chave`, para o angular é melhor pois ele controla o `$scope`.

e criaria também a função de imprimir em angular chamando através do `ng-click`, e o *disable* eu utilizaria a própria variável do `$scope.chave`.

tenha certeza que sua variável chave esta com dados.

```
<br/>**javascript:**<br/>
$scope.submitForm = function() {<br/>
        $http({<br/>
          method  : 'POST',<br/>
          url     : 'validar.php',<br/>
          dataType: 'json',<br/>
          data : dados,<br/>
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}<br/>
         })<br/>
         .success(function(data) {<br/>
            if (data.errors) {<br/>
              $scope.erro = data.errors.errovalidar;<br/>
            } else {<br/>
              $scope.chave = data.chave;<br/>
              $('#imprimir-danfe').removeAttr('disabled');<br/>
            }<br/>
          })<br/>
    };<br/>
$scope.imprimir = function() {<br/>
        $http({<br/>
          method  : 'POST',<br/>
          url     : 'imprimir.php',<br/>
          data : chave,<br/>
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}<br/>
         })<br/>
    };<br/>
**html** <br/>

input type="button" ng-click="imprimir" ng-disabled="chave==undefined"
```

Comment: Mas a pergunta não se refere a Angular. (colocaram a etiqueta depois do meu comentário rs).